# How can I ensure that the columns in MySQL does NOT display the default "0" if user fails to enter data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a code for an online survey which has a few text (form) fields into which users enter their data. My difficulty is that in the form fields which require a digit, if the user fails to enter a digit, the default "0" keeps appearing in the column of the MySQL database. How can I prevent this? What I would prefer is that if a user forgets or simply does not want to enter his age or his height, the age and height columns in MySQL will simply remain empty. Can I achieve that wish with the following code (which I obtained from YouTube and simply changed the field names)?:

```
      <?php

       mysqli_connect('localhost','root','pswd','database');

       if (isset($_POST['age']) && isset($_POST['heightininches'])) {

             $age = 'age';
             $heightininches = 'heightininches';

                if(!empty($age) && !empty($heightininches)) {

                        $age = 'age';   
                        $heightininches = 'heightininches'; 

                }  else {

                         $age = '';   // will this line ensure that column will not display "0"
                         $heightininches = ''; 

                }

            }


        <form action = "pagoda.php"   method = "POST">

        Age: <input type = "text"  name = "age">
             <input type = "text"  name = "heightininches">
             <input type = "text"  value = "Submit">

        </form>
```

I have two further questions: Given that the code above has '&&', does this mean that if I do not enter any data in EITHER the age field OR the heightininches field, then BOTH these columns in the database will not be populated? Does the '&&' tie both the fields together? Or do they remain separate?
My other question is: the 'isset' function has an argument which looks like '$_POST['age']', but the 'empty' function has an argument which looks like '$age'. Why? Why doesn't 'empty' have an argument like '$_POST['age']'?

Comment: did you try with $age = null;

Comment: No, I didn't. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

In the database, configure the field age to accept null and the default value to be null, that's how it works.